# Z3: ParseSMTLIB2File/String

Tags: java, api, z3

I used ParseSMTLIB2File to parse an smt2 file Context.smt2 which has declarations of datatypes, constants, and functions; e.g.

```
    ; Sort Declarations
    (declare-sort tla_sort_Str)
    (declare-const x tla_sort_Str)
    (declare-const y tla_sort_Str)
    (declare-const z tla_sort_Str)
```

And then, I used ParseSMTLIB2String to parse a string "(assert (= x y))". The following is my code:

```
     BoolExpr expr = ctx.parseSMTLIB2File("Context.smt2", null, null, null, null);
     String str = "(assert (= x y))";
     BoolExpr assert = ctx.parseSMTLIB2String(str, null, null, null, null);
```

Unfortunately, I received an error. I guess the reason is that ctx doesn't know what tla_sort_Str, x and y are. If no, how can I pass information in Context.smt2 to parseSMTLIB2String? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what all the 'null' arguments are for (one of them is to supply sorts that have been constructed earlier).

Not however that parseSMTLIB2File does *not* support all features of SMT2 or any extensions. It will basically read the assertions and ignore everything else, possibly including sort declarations. SMT2 is an interaction language, but within the scope of parseSMTLIB2File there is no interaction, thus no commands will be excuted, e.g., the most imporant example is the `(check-sat)` command, which is not executed.

Comment: Thanks you, Christoph. I should have declared fresh sorts and variables before, and then pass them to parseSMTLIB2String().